# How to create PDF in cyrillic with js

Tags: javascript, pdf, utf-8, jspdf

I have a problem with language in `pdf` format.
I have this code in [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/1/), but when I put the word "Книга" in one of columns and want to download pdf file the text look like this =830. 
My question is how to add in code `utf 8`

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12

Comment: You might have gotten quicker answers on here if you had tagged your question correctly for the technology you are using. Yes, you're using Javascript but your Fiddle specifically uses jsPDF, which is important information in your context.

Answer (score 2):

As already commented by @b2238488, jsPDF doesn't support any special characters, nor does it support embedding (let alone subsetting) of fonts into PDF files. This makes it pretty much useless if you want to use cyrillic or any other language that requires UTF-8 support.